# ngmap for google maps v3 does not work on internet explorer 11

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to use [ngMap](https://ngmap.github.io/) in my application but it gives this error on internet explorer 11:

```
"0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied."
```

But it works in google chrome without any errors. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this on [Microsoft support docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/908356):

> "You may receive an "Access Denied" or a "Permission Denied" scripting
>   error message when you browse a secure Web site that contains multiple
>   frames"

**CAUSE**

> This issue occurs because Internet Explorer does not correctly
>   evaluate Internet security zones before it finishes processing the
>   .pac file. When this occurs, Internet Explorer may assign a URL to an
>   unexpected zone.

**WORKAROUND**

> To work around this issue, add the Web site that is affected to the
>   Trusted sites security zone in Internet Explorer. To do this, follow
>   these steps:
>   1. Start Internet Explorer.
>   2. On the Tools menu, click Internet Options.
>   3. On the Security tab, click Trusted sites, and then click Sites.
>   4. In the Add this Web site to the zone box, type the URL of the Web site that is affected, and then click Add.
>   5. Click OK. Note You can also configure Internet Explorer settings by using Group Policy. F

Also, try if this problem persists in other browsers like Chrome and Firefox